# access outlook emails in local machine while running the flask app from windows sever

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a flask app that reads outlook emails, my code works fine in my local machine when I run it on localhost.
But when I changed the app run to "0.0.0.0" to be able to run from different machines while the flask app is running on a Windows 2008 server, I am not able to access my local outlook.
What I want is to run my script on windows server, and be able to successfully read my outlook emails from any machine locally. I am really not sure how can I do that.

Comment: You need to be more specific than *my script doesn't work*.... Please have a look at how to create a [mcve].... Aso - when you say read outlook emails - is that by accessing the pst file outlook has or accessing via IMAP... depending which - without suitable access - you're probably find it impossible. The rest is probably just access control... However, with more details included in an [edit] to your question - it maybe answerable.

Comment: I am using win32 lib to read outlook emails. My code works fine in localhost. But, when I was running it in Windows server and try to access my app in local machine, I wasn't able to access my outlook instead the server's outlook is getting dispatched when I use win32com.client.Dispatch.

Comment: Is there a way I can access my outlook on local system while running it on win server. I don't know how can I do that.

Comment: None that I know of... that's why it's best to just read from an imap folder... (then you don't have to automate care what system you're running it on)... Don't forget to [edit] your question to include what you're trying to do and the code you're using that you'd like to see if you can adapt to work given your requirements so it's not considered too broad.

Comment: I am accessing it via IMAP using win32com

Comment: Now I'm confused... is your email data coming from trying to dispatch to an Outlook instance or is what you're after ultimately accessible via an IMAP email server?

Comment: by dispatching outlook instance

Comment: And then outlook is using imap to access it's mailbox... You really need to clarify with [edit]s to your question... if you've got an imap server and know the login/password for a user account then you can directly use the Python `imaplib`library and login there and get what you need and then you don't have to worry about any of this as long as where you're running it can access the server.

Comment: outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
    ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    emails = ns.GetDefaultFolder(6).Items

Comment: That's MAPI not IMAP so that's different and please edit your question with that information - it's hard to read and will get lost in the comments... along with the error/incorrect results you're getting and the other info. about what you're trying to do...